# Is the empty set Ø a basis of itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am aware that span Ø = {0} and thus the empty set Ø is a basis for the zero vector space, but can the empty set can also be considered a basis for itself? An argument for this could go like: the empty set is trivially linearly independent, and since Ø ⊆ {0}, it seems that the empty set can generate itself. Hence, the empty set would meet the requirements for being its own basis. However, I am unsure about the second part of the argument about the empty set generating itself because it appears to generate more than just itself being it also generates the zero vector, but this may not be problematic.

Comment: Since a basis is defined for a vector space and $\emptyset$ is not a vector space, I see no definition for a basis of $\emptyset.$ Your observation that $\emptyset$ also generates the zero vector is a good observation too.

Comment: I don't know if this is the correct translation of  what I really think of it : "How many angels can dance on the head of a pin".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\emptyset$ is not a vector space, it makes no sense to talk about a basis of that set (in the Linear Algebra sense).